# Как решать эти странные задания с ЕГЭ? (№16)

Tags: python, рекурсия

В заданиях #16, которые составляют малоизвестные личности мне часто встречаются задачи, в которых идёт переполнение стека (я вот сомневаюсь, что на экзамене для школьников может быть задание на рекурсию, которую рвёт на части даже если передать в неё '1').
Мне интересно, это ошибка составителя задания или это я что-то делаю не так.

```py
from functools import lru_cache
from sys import setrecursionlimit

setrecursionlimit(3000)


@lru_cache()
def F(n: int):
    if n >= 10000:
        return n
    elif n % 2:
        return F(n + 2) + 1
    else:
        return F(n + 2) - 3


print(F(4))
```

[image: Задание]

Comment: "Малоизвестные личности" - молодцы! Красивая задача.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не все задания такого типа нужно решать написанием программы "в лоб" по условию, некоторые из них следует предварительно преобразовать, а некоторые можно решить и без написания программы, как и в данном случае.

```
F(94) = F(96) - 3 = F(98) - 6 …
F(80) = F(82) - 3 = F(84) - 6 …
```

Очевидно, что с нечётным `n` мы никогда не столкнёмся, тогда имеем:

```
F(94) - F(80) = (F(10000) - ((10000-94)/2) * 3) - (F(10000) - ((10000 - 80))/2 * 3)) =
(10000 - 14859) - (10000 - 14880) = 21
```

Comment: Ясно, спасибо :)